# How to add support for xunit's Theory attribute in Approvaltests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net, approval-tests

When I try to use approvals with my unit test decorated with `[Theory]` attribute it says:

```
System.Exception: System.Exception : Approvals is not set up to use your test framework.
It currently supports [NUnit, MsTest, MbUnit, xUnit.net]
To add one use ApprovalTests.StackTraceParsers.StackTraceParser.AddParser() method to add implementation of ApprovalTests.StackTraceParsers.IStackTraceParser with support for your testing framework.
To learn how to implement one see http://blog.approvaltests.com/2012/01/creating-namers.html
   at ApprovalTests.StackTraceParsers.StackTraceParser.Parse(StackTrace stackTrace)
   at ApprovalTests.Namers.UnitTestFrameworkNamer..ctor()
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.GetDefaultNamer()
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.Verify(IApprovalWriter writer)
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.Verify(Object text)
```

Seems like it recognizes `[Fact]` attributes only. I tried to follow the [link from stacktrace](http://blog.approvaltests.com/2012/01/creating-namers.html)  but there is nothing about how to plug in your own namer/parser into approvals.

Is there any entry point where I can add my own namer/parser? Itself it seems to be trivial, the only question is how to use it:

```
 public class TheoryNamer : AttributeStackTraceParser
    {
        protected override string GetAttributeType()
        {
            return typeof(TheoryAttribute).FullName;
        }

        public override string ForTestingFramework
        {
            get { return "xUnit Extensions"; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple parts to this answer & question.

1. How to add
2. The Namer
3. Dealing with data driven tests in approvaltests

**1) How to add**

Adding is simple (if a bit rough)
The method mentioned should have been static, but it works none the less.

> To add one use
>   ApprovalTests.StackTraceParsers.StackTraceParser.AddParser() method to
>   add implementation of
>   ApprovalTests.StackTraceParsers.IStackTraceParser with support for
>   your testing framework.

so you'll need to do a

```
new StackTraceParser().AddParser(new TheoryNamer());
```

I apologize for this, and it will be static in the next version (v.21)

**2) The Namer**

The Namer is suppose to generate a unique name for each approved/received file. This is normally done on the name of the method, however the name here will not be unique as a theory based test will be data driven and therefore have multiple calls to the same method.

```
Naming:  classname.methodname(optional: .additionalInformation).received.extension
```

As such, you will probably have to include additional information in the method it's self

```
public class StringTests1
{
    [Theory,
    InlineData("goodnight moon"),
    InlineData("hello world")]
    public void Contains(string input)
    {
        NamerFactory.AdditionalInformation = input;  // <- important
        Approvals.Verify(transform(input));
    }
}
```

**3) Dealing with data driven tests in approvaltests**

To be honest, in most cases, the data driven method of approach in Approval Tests isn't thru  parameters in the Method Decorators. It is usually thru the VerifyAll with a lambda transform. For Example the above might look like

```
[Fact]
public void UpperCase()
{
    var inputs = new[]{"goodnight moon","hello world"};
    Approvals.VerifyAll(inputs, i => "{0} => {1}".FormatWith(i, i.ToUpperInvariant()));
}
```

Which would create the received file:

```
goodnight moon => GOODNIGHT MOON
hello world => HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I didn't notice that `StackTraceParser.parsers` is indeed static :)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to inherit TheoryNamer class from **XUnitStackTraceParser**.

It works perfect!
I think it would be cool to add such class into ApprovalTests.StackTraceParsers namespace :)

```
public class XUnitTheoryStackTraceParser : XUnitStackTraceParser
{
    public const string TheoryAttribute = "Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute";

    protected override string GetAttributeType()
    {
        return TheoryAttribute;
    }
}

public class ApproveTheoryTest
{
    static ApproveTheoryTest()
    {
        StackTraceParser.AddParser(new XUnitTheoryStackTraceParser());
    }

    [Theory]
    [UseReporter(typeof(DiffReporter))]
    [InlineData("file1.txt")]
    [InlineData("file2.txt")]
    public void approve_file(string fileName)
    {
        NamerFactory.AdditionalInformation = fileName;
        Approvals.Verify("sample text");
    }
}
```